# How to express negation with symbol in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I query activities for a given week except for the day with name equal to the string "summary"?

```
Activity.where(:week => wk, :day => "Summary").each do |daily_activity|
end
```

How do you express the negation? And show the activities for each day in the week, but not when the day is "Summary" (as it's not an actual day).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly with a hash, but you can do it with something like the following:

```
Activity.where(:week => wk).where('day != ?', 'Summary')
```

If you want expanded options for finders, check out the [squeel gem](https://github.com/ernie/squeel).